# Accelerometer frequency low when display is dimmed

Tags: android, wear-os, accelerometer, sensors, android-wake-lock

I'm working on a wearable app that should capture all motions from the accelerometer with at least 30Hz. When I keep the screen on with a `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` everything works fine, but when I use `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` the sampling frequency is reduced to about 6Hz.

I suspect this behaviour is implemented in the firmware of the device. I had two tablets who behaved differently - one did allow to read accelerometer data with `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` and the other didn't while the screen was off. Does someone know a way to get arround this?

In this project I'm using a Huawei Watch 6325 and a Polar M600 Smartwatch who both behave the same.

Comment: I am not really sure if this can help, but you can try to check this documentation about [Stuck partial wake locks](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/wakelock).